# Pandas series - generating list of all columns with some condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have data in pandas. series type. The index is a list (of some numbers) and the value for a given index is again a list (of some other numbers).

I want to do the following: I take all the indices, which are list, that differ by only one element (ex: [1,2,3] and [1,2,4] differ by one element) and then I produce a new series whose indices are the unions of these indices and corresponding values are intersection of values of their respective indices . (ex: if index - [1,2,3] has value [11,21,13] and index-[1,2,4] has value [11,22,13,12], then new series has index [1,2,3,4] with value [11,13].)

I have been trying for so long but I am confused with taking unions and intersections.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the set of indices that only differ by one element is non-trivial, since multiple groups can arise that share individual indices. Furthermore, a compound index may come up with different sets of values, as you can see below. I advise you to use caution with such a rule when combining indices.

I've included a couple of helpers to get a generator of the index groups. The intersections are done easily with sets in the `aggregate` function. Finally, a copy of the original series is made to hold the new data, otherwise it interferes with the group generation if you append to the same series:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

def match(index=None, seed=None, dist=1):
    seed_set = set(seed)
    index_set = set(index)
    if len(index_set - seed_set) == dist and seed_set.issubset(index_set):
        return True
    return False


def index_groups(series):
    indices = list(series.index)
    # Get unique index group seeds
    seeds = set()
    for i in indices:
        seeds |= set(combinations(i, len(i)-1))
    # Produce index groups
    for seed in seeds:
        group = [i for i in indices if match(index=i, seed=seed)]
        if len(group) > 1:
            yield group


def aggregate_indices(series, index_list=[]):
    new_index = set(index_list[0])
    for next_index in index_list[1:]:
        new_index = new_index | set(next_index)
    new_index = tuple(new_index)
    new_data = set(series[index_list[0]])
    for next_index in index_list[1:]:
        new_data = new_data & set(series[next_index])
    new_data = list(new_data)
    return pd.Series(index=[new_index], data=[new_data])

s = pd.Series(index=[(1,2,3), (2,3,4), (1,3,4)],
              data=[[11,12,13,14], [13,14,15,16], [11,12,15,16]])

new_s = s.copy()
for index_group in list(index_groups(s)):
    new_s = new_s.append(aggregate_indices(s, index_list=index_group))

print(new_s)

"""
Out:
    (1, 2, 3)       [11, 12, 13, 14]
    (2, 3, 4)       [13, 14, 15, 16]
    (1, 3, 4)       [11, 12, 15, 16]
    (1, 2, 3, 4)            [11, 12]
    (1, 2, 3, 4)            [13, 14]
    (1, 2, 3, 4)            [16, 15]
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a really a pandas question but just a combination one. In addition, using lists as index is **bad**: a list is an unhashable type, so you can use neither `loc` nor `[]` on it. IMHO so you should immediately convert it to a manageable container like a `dict`, with tuples (hashable type) as keys and lists as values.

Assuming your series is `s`:

```
[1, 2, 3]        [11, 21, 13]
[1, 2, 4]    [11, 22, 13, 12]
dtype: object
```

I would use:

```
data = {tuple(i): j for i,j in s.items()}
for i,j in itertools.combinations(data.keys(), 2):
    si = set(i)
    sj = set(j)
    if len(si.difference(sj)) == 1:
        key = si.union(sj)
        val = set(data[i]).intersection(set(data[j]))
        print((i,data[i]), (j, data[j]), '=>', (list(key), list(val)))
```

Which gives as expected:

```
((1, 2, 3), [11, 21, 13]) ((1, 2, 4), [11, 22, 13, 12]) => ([1, 2, 3, 4], [11, 13])
```